# How to return other condition based result in orElse in dart based firstWhere

Tags: validation, flutter, dart, conditional-statements, where-clause

I have gone through some of the conditions based threads here on stack for the same type of questions but the output is not what I am looking for.

below is what I am currently doing with my code which is working but is bad practice from my perspective though I can be wrong and is the way things needs to be done!

method 1:

```
transData = data.translations.firstWhere(
            (element) => element.langCode == langCode,
            orElse: () => null);
        transData = (transData == null)
            ? data.translations.firstWhere(
                (element) => element.langCode == 'en-IN',
                orElse: () => null)
            : transData;
```

method 2:

```
transData = data.translations.firstWhere(
            (element) => element.langCode == langCode,
            orElse: () => data.translations.firstWhere(
                (element) => element.langCode == 'en-IN',
                orElse: () => null));
```

you can clearly see what I want is check if the given condition is true then return result based on that else based on default `langCode`. for this `orElse` is the best place to do so but getting error for the same if the code is as following:

code:

```
transData = data.translations.firstWhere(
            (element) => element.langCode == langCode,
            orElse: (element) => element.langCode == 'en-IN');
```

error:

```
The argument type 'ModelName Function(dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ModelName Function()'.
```

I don't want a null result as because the default `langCode` based record always exist if a entry for a parent record exist.

Answer (score 0):

`orElse` should return a default value, not a boolean.

```
transData = data.translations.firstWhere(
            (element) => element.langCode == langCode,
            orElse: () => aDefaultTranslation);
```

Comment: but that value needs to be based on given condition. also what is `aDefaultTranslation` in my case ?

Comment: `aDefaultTranslation` is an instance of `translations`. You should decide what is the default value if none is found. If you want to provide a secondary condition in the event that the first one fails, then you are probably looking for an `or` condition, and not the `orElse` clause. The `orElse` clause is basically a `getOrElse` or `??` in Dart. 

Based on your code snippet, I'm assuming you actually want:

`element.langCode == langCode || element.langCode == 'en-IN'` as your condition.

Comment: so the answer will be `transData = data.translations.firstWhere(
            (element) => element.langCode == langCode,
            or: (element) => element.langCode == 'en-IN');` ?

Comment: I think it will be:

```
transData = data.translations.firstWhere( (element) => element.langCode == langCode || element.langCode == 'en-IN');
```

Comment: Let me check. I never though of this as this is the basic :< my bad :P

Comment: just "or" doesnt seem to be available anymore